# React Error - Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have received this error whenever I close my **loginPage** component. It closes in the socket.on('LOGIN_RESULT') inside the **sendLoginRequest** function. I need to use a **useEffect** function but I do not know the correct way to implement it into my **loginPage** component.

[image: React Error]

loginPage.js ------

```
import React from 'react';
import loginstyles from './loginpage.module.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { LOGIN } from '../messageStore/actions';
import SectionLoader from '../../components/login/SectionLoader';
import * as SectionGetter from '../../components/login/SectionGetter';
import ClientSocket from '../../socket/ClientSocket';

const loginPage = props => {

    //Pop up window that a user can use to login
    const socket = ClientSocket.getSocket();

    const [loginData, setLoginData] = React.useState({ //Temporary login info before confirmed and push into Redux
        email: '',
        pass: '',
    });

    const [loginState, setloginState] = React.useState(SectionGetter.GET_EMAILSECTION(''));

    const [sentData, setSentData] = React.useState(false);


    const changeLogin = event => { //Changes the temporary login info the user entered
        const name = event.target.name;
        const value = event.target.value;

        setLoginData({
            ...loginData,
            [name]: value
        });
    }

    const validateInfo = () => {
        if(loginData.email != "") {
            if(loginData.pass != "") {
                return true;
            } else {
                setloginState(SectionGetter.GET_PASSWORDSECTION('Please enter your password'));
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            setloginState(SectionGetter.GET_EMAILSECTION('Please enter your email'));
            return false;
        }
    }

    function loginIntoApp() {
        if(!sentData) {
            if(validateInfo()) {
                setloginState(SectionGetter.GET_LOADINGSECTION);
                setSentData(true);
                sendLoginRequest();
            }
        }
    }

    function sendLoginRequest() {
            socket.emit('LOGIN', {
                email: loginData.email,
                pass: loginData.pass
            });
            socket.on('LOGIN_RESULT', data => {   
                if(data.result === 'SUCCESS') {
                    props.dispatch(LOGIN(data.username, loginData.email, loginData.pass));
                    props.dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_EXIT', payload: null} );
                } else {
                    setloginState(SectionGetter.GET_WRONGDETAILS_SECTION(''));
                }
                setSentData(false);
            });
    }

    const onNextSection = () => {
        if(loginState.type === SectionGetter.PASSWORD) {
            loginIntoApp();
            return;
        }
        setloginState(SectionGetter.nextSection(loginState));
    }

    const exit = () => {
        props.dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_EXIT', payload: null });
    }

    return (
        /*<div className={loginstyles.loginArea}>
            <form className={loginstyles.loginform}>
                <div className={loginstyles.logincomponent}>
                    <label><div className={loginstyles.descriptiontext}>Email: </div>
                    <input type="text" className={loginstyles.loginform_textarea} />
                    </label><br />
                </div>
                
                <div className={loginstyles.logincomponent}>
                    <label><div className={loginstyles.descriptiontext}>pass: </div>
                    <input type="pass" className={loginstyles.loginform_textarea} />
                    </label><br />
                </div>

                <div className={loginstyles.logincomponent}>
                    <label>
                        Remember me <input type="checkbox" name="remember" className={loginstyles.loginform_remember} />
                    </label>
                </div>
                
                <div className={loginstyles.logincomponent} id={loginstyles.login}>
                    <button type="submit" className={loginstyles.loginform_submit}>Login</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>*/
        <div className={loginstyles.loginArea}>
            <input type="image" src="/exit.svg" border="0" alt="Submit" onClick={exit} className={loginstyles.exit_image}/>
            <SectionLoader section={loginState.section} onNextSection={onNextSection.bind(this)} changeLogin={changeLogin.bind(this)} error={loginState.error} login={loginIntoApp.bind(this)}/>
        </div>
        
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        email: state.loginDetails.email,
        password: state.loginDetails.password
    };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(loginPage);
```

index.js ----

```
function Home(props) {


  const setLoginState = state => {
    console.log(state);
    if(state) {
      props.dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_ACTIVE', payload: null });
    } else {
      props.dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_INACTIVE', payload: null });
    }
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
          <title>AXSHS Live</title>
      </Head>
      {props.loginActive === true ? 
        <LoginPage/>
        : 
        null
      }
      <div className={props.loginActive === true ? homepage.app_loginactive : homepage.app}>
        
        <div className={homepage.home}>
          
          <Navbar username={props.details.username} loginState={setLoginState}/>
          
          <Grid />
          
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    details: state.loginDetails,
    loginActive: state.loginActive
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home);
```

What is the correct way to implement a React useEffect cleanup function when you are using socket.io and redux. I'm not sure wether its my socket that is causing the react state update or the redux connect function.

Comment: In myopinion no one responded because you didnt minimize the problem, and instead pasted all your code bro...

Comment: please create a code sandbox